# Can different domain name share the same Cache Storage

Tags: javascript, service-worker, browser-cache

I try to get the  Cache Storage resource from other domain name that are both based other server side (like http://192.168.0.203:3050/ and http://127.0.0.1:5000/ they are connect in intranet).
I want to got the cache from http://192.168.0.203:3050/ that cache with service-worker and let  my side http://127.0.0.1:5000/ to use the cdn script in the cache from http://192.168.0.203:3050/  .

[image]

This is the cache in port:2028 .
[image]

This is the cache in  http://192.168.0.203:3050/

Is there any way to let the http://127.0.0.1:5000/ get the same cache from http://192.168.0.203:3050/

Comment: That would be very bad if `http://evilwebiste.com` could access the caches from `https://arandombank.com`. Why would anyone use an authentication system at all if third parties could read the fetched resources anyway? For instance, chances are quite high that the item at index `1` in your screenshot contains a password in the Request that's used as key in the Cache.

Comment: Yes, I see .I think my goal is to share the cdn to another server that can not connect the internet but connect intranet of my site.